# Extracting city names in the text form from the function CountryData

Tags: databases

I was planning to create an array with all capital cities in Europe using the following command:

`CountryData["Europe", "CapitalCity"]`

But unfortunately, it returns all results in rectangular frames. How can I get rid of them and get a simple text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the functions [`CanonicalName`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CanonicalName.html) and `CommonName`:

```
eucc = CountryData["Europe", "CapitalCity"]
```

[image]

```
CanonicalName @ eucc
```

[image]

```
CommonName @ eucc
```

[image]

You can also use `EntityValue` `"Name"` to get `CommonName[eucc]`:

```
EntityValue[eucc, "Name"] == CommonName[eucc]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`EntityValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EntityValue) with the property "CanonicalName":

```
EntityValue[CountryData["Europe","CapitalCity"],"CanonicalName"]
```

> {{"Tirana", "Tirana", "Albania"}, {"AndorraLaVella", "AndorraLaVella",
> "Andorra"}, {"Vienna", "Vienna", "Austria"}, {"Minsk", "Minsk",
> "Belarus"}, {"Brussels", "Brussels", "Belgium"}, {"Sarajevo",
> "FederacijaBosnaIHercegovina", "BosniaHerzegovina"}, {"Sofia", "SofijaGrad",
> "Bulgaria"}, {"Zagreb", "GradZagreb", "Croatia"}, {"Nicosia", "Nicosia",
> "Cyprus"}, {"Prague", "Prague", "CzechRepublic"}, {"Copenhagen",
> "Copenhagen", "Denmark"}, {"Tallinn", "Harju", "Estonia"}, {"Torshavn",
> "Stromo", "FaroeIslands"}, {"Helsinki", "Uusimaa", "Finland"}, {"Paris",
> "IleDeFrance", "France"}, {"Berlin", "Berlin", "Germany"}, {"Gibraltar",
> "Gibraltar", "Gibraltar"}, {"Athens", "Attiki",
> "Greece"}, {"SaintPeterPort", "SaintPeterPort", "Guernsey"}, {"Budapest",
> "Budapest", "Hungary"}, {"Reykjavik", "Hofudhborgarsvaedhi",
> "Iceland"}, {"Dublin", "Dublin", "Ireland"}, {"Douglas", "Douglas",
> "IsleOfMan"}, {"Rome", "Lazio", "Italy"}, {"SaintHelier", "SaintHelier",
> "Jersey"}, {"Pristina", "Pristina", "Kosovo"}, {"Riga", "Riga",
> "Latvia"}, {"Vaduz", "Vaduz", "Liechtenstein"}, {"Vilnius", "Vilniaus",
> "Lithuania"}, {"Luxemburg", "Luxembourg", "Luxembourg"}, {"Skopje",
> "Skopje", "Macedonia"}, {"Valletta", "Valletta", "Malta"}, {"Chisinau",
> "Chisinau", "Moldova"}, {"MonacoVille", "Monaco", "Monaco"}, {"Podgorica",
> "Podgorica", "Montenegro"}, {"Amsterdam", "NoordHolland",
> "Netherlands"}, {"Oslo", "Oslo", "Norway"}, {"Warsaw", "Mazowieckie",
> "Poland"}, {"Lisbon", "Lisboa", "Portugal"}, {"Bucharest", "Bucharest",
> "Romania"}, {"SanMarino", "SanMarino", "SanMarino"}, {"Belgrade",
> "CentralSerbia", "Serbia"}, {"Bratislava", "Bratislavsky",
> "Slovakia"}, {"Ljubljana", "Osrednjeslovenska", "Slovenia"}, {"Madrid",
> "Madrid", "Spain"}, {"Longyearbyen", "Svalbard", "Svalbard"}, {"Stockholm",
> "Stockholm", "Sweden"}, {"Bern", "Bern", "Switzerland"}, {"Kiev", "Kiev",
> "Ukraine"}, {"London", "GreaterLondon", "UnitedKingdom"}, {"VaticanCity",
> "VaticanCity", "VaticanCity"}}

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for. But, actually, there should be "Name" instead of "CanonicalName".